# How to package config.yml and resources in $project--0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar

Tags: maven, dropwizard

I've a drop wizard project which has the following directory structure:

```
basedir
    pom.xml
    config.yml
    src
     main
      resources
       myresource.xml
The build portion of 
<build>
    <finalName>project-${version}</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>shade</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <transformers>
                            <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                <mainClass>project-package.App</mainClass>
                            </transformer>
                            <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ServicesResourceTransformer">
                            </transformer>
                        </transformers>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

When I run my code from Eclipse, I use command as follows:
$mypackage.App server config.yml 
It works fine and I can read the file under resources directory.
When I use mvn to build, in the snapshot jar created, it does not include config.yml and the path to "myresource.xml" is missing even though it is included in the snapshot.jar in the basedir. So, when I run it from my jar file, my code does not find it as resources.
How should I change the pom.xml to include config.yml and package the resource directory such a way that it is accessible as resource.

Comment: The main idea of the configurations in `dropwizard` IS to externalize the configuration. The user/administrator of the dropwizard application IS responsible to supply the correct configuration when starting the application for the given system and/or environment. And not to use some possibly unknown default configuration. You keep the real configs somewhere (another version control repository for example) SEPARATELY from the code. You could distribute a sample configuration but there are BETTER ways to distribute documentation.

Comment: That is correct. We should keep the config files separately from the build.

Answer (score 0):

It is really strange that

```
this.getClass().getResource("myresource.xml")
```

does work in IDE but NOT when you run it from a jar.

```
this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("myresource.xml")
```

works both inside IDE and from jar.

That resolves the resources issue. However, I need an answer for how to package config.yml file. Should I supply separately in addition to the jar file?

Comment: Please check my comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42884004/how-to-package-config-yml-and-resources-in-project-0-0-1-snapshot-jar#comment72966041_42884004